# How to send data to database using localhost

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, localhost

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy9FF.png)I create a registiration form. I have register database and member table in mysql.

My register.php file is:

```
<?php
//verileri gönderebilmek için önce bir veri tabanına bağlanmamız gerekir.
include"connect.php"; //connect.php adında bir dosya açtık(veri tabanı kısmında kullanıcaz)

//html deki register formdan gelen verileri register.php ye almış oluyoruz..
$name = $_POST["firstname"]; //veriler POST ile gönderilir.
$sname = $_POST["surname"];
$male = $_POST["male"];
$fename = $_POST["female"];
$email = $_POST["eMail"];
$number = $_POST["phonenum"];
$password = $_POST["pword"];

//veritabanı tablosunda eşitliyoruz ex: member_name eşitse member_name e gibi.
$register=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO register SET
  member_name=:member_name,  
  member_surname=:member_surname,
  member_male=:member_male,
  member_female=:member_female,
  member_mail=:member_mail,
  member_number=:member_number,
  member_password=:member_password

");

//atama işlemini gerçekleştiriyoruz ex: member_name e POST tan gelen firstname i atıyoruz..
$insert=$register->execute(array(
  'member_name' => $_POST['firstname'],
  'member_surname' => $_POST['surname'],
  'member_male' => $_POST['male'],
  'member_female' => $_POST['female'],
  'member_mail' => $_POST['eMail'],
  'member_number' => $_POST['phonenum'],
  'member_password' => $_POST['pword']

));

//insert işleminin başarılı olup olmadığını kontrol ediyoruz
//inser işlemi başarılı olursa buraya yönlendir

if($insert){
    Header("Location:index.php?durum=ok");
}
//insert işlemi başarısız olursa buraya yönlendir
else{
    Header("Location:xml_get_current_byte_index(parser).php?durum=no");

}

?>
```

I get this error when I want to register members on the form using localhost ----> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'register' in C:\wamp64\www\register\connect.php on line 7

( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'register' in C:\wamp64\www\register\connect.php on line 7

My connect.php file is:

```
<?php
//mysql de oluşturduğumuz veri tabanına erişim sağlamak için bunu kullanıyoruz 
try {
    //mysql:host=localhost(local hostta çalıştığımız için)
    //dbname=member (oluşturduğum veritabanının ismi member)
    //phpmyadmin için root(kullanıcı adı) ''(şifresiz girdiğimiz için boş)
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=register;charset=utf8",'root','');

}
catch (PDOExpception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Your database name (register) is wrong. Please check it

Comment: i did but its not wrong. Could something else happen?

Comment: `PDOExpception` < you have a typo in there. It should read as `PDOException`.

Comment: Are you sure about `dbname=register` and your query? They both bear the same name.

Comment: The query should be "INSERT INTO member..." - but I still think his DB server address is wrong

Answer (score -1):

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'register' is a clear indication that your MySql could not find the database name that you are specifying in your connection string.

It is very much possible that you might have 'register' database at some other database host and not localhost.
You may want to check if you have other databases present on your system like XAMPP or MAMP etc..

To further support your claim please if 'register' exists and you believe that your connection string is correct, kindly share screenshot of either phpmyadmin from wamp with the database name 'register' and then we will be able to help further.

Comment: I added my screenshot, please check. It is top on the my question

Comment: Okay your screenshot shows the following observations :
1) Mysql is running on port 3308 , you need to add that to your PDO connection string , 
update it as follows : 

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3308;dbname=register;charset=utf8",'root','');

Comment: Second observation is that your table name is member
so your insert query will not work,
replace "INSERT INTO REGISTER.." with "INSERT INTO MEMBER..."